# UIButton colour changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am making an 'info' button, using Xcode's built in button type, "UIButtonTypeInfoLight".

This is my code:

```
self.helpButton= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
[self.helpButton addTarget:self
           action:@selector(showHelp)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.helpButton.frame = CGRectMake(280.0, 440.0, 20, 20);
[self.view addSubview:self.helpButton];
```

However, there is a problem. My app contains a scroll view with 3 different view controllers. One blue, one red, and one green.

The icon looks fine on the page that the app opens up with (blue):

[image]

However, when i swipe to the green or red pages, the button seems to stay blue, and not transparent like I want it to be:

[image]
[image]

How can I stop it from doing this? I just want the icon to be transparent?

Answer (score 13):

The UIButtonTypeInfoLight uses the application's tint color, which default to the blue you see.  What you could do is change the UIButton's tint color on the fly:

```
[infoButton setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```